# jQuery > Targeting dynamically created select

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has 8 dropdown boxes that are filled with database entries (or blank if none present).

For example:

```
<select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select1st' class='listbox medium'>
<select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select2nd' class='listbox medium'>
```

and so on through 8 entries.

What I'm trying to do (eventually) is when one of these select boxes gets changed it will use jQuery post and update a text input field.

What's happening right now is that when I use the following jQuery I get an alert for each one of the select boxes (instead of just the one that I changed):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("[id^=admin_select]").change(function() {
 alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
</script>
```

Right now this is expected behaviour since I'm telling it to match any ID that starts with admin_select.  What I need to know is, is there a way I can use this code once and not have to write it out for each admin_select1st, admin_select2nd, admin_select3rd, etc, repeating my code 8 times?

Comment: Your code seems to be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2bLBX/

Comment: It should be called only once. The handler is bound to each drop downs and `.change` will be triggered only for the drop down that value is changed.

Comment: Possibly use jQuery each: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @BillyMoat actually, that should be automatically handled by jQuery internally when multiple items are selected by one selector.

Comment: Thanks all, I see the issue now.  I had the script code inside of my while loop that built the form, so it was showing up 8 times instead of just the once.  Hence the 8 alerts.  Now that I move it outside of the while loop it won't work at all though :P  I should be able to get it from here though. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the comments below your question what you've got now should work.

Alternatively you could try something like this

```
$("[id^=admin_select]").each(

function( intIndex ){


    $(this).change(function(){
    alert(intIndex);
    });
}
);
```

I haven't tested it though but it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the duplicate alerts was that the  was located inside the while loops that generated the 8 select boxes so the code was repeated 8 times and therefore alerted 8 times.

Moved it outside the while loop and now it's working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input text field ID id **result**:

if you don't want keep the elements by matching any IDs, you can get them by class selector; if you need to bind several time the portion of code, you can use unbind

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".listbox.medium").each(function() {
        $(this).unbind("change").bind("change", function() {
        $("#result").val(sel.val());
        });
    });
 });
```

Full code here

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".listbox.medium").each(function() {
                $(this).change(function() {
                    $("#result").val($(this).val());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(78, 120, 178);"><br />
    <input type="text" id="result" value="" />
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select1st' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select2nd' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select3st' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select4nd' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select5st' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select6nd' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select7st' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>7</option>
    </select>
    <select name='admin_id[]' id='admin_select8nd' class='listbox medium'>
        <option></option>
        <option>8</option>
    </select>
</body>
```